# Tags for Sipser questions?

Tags: discussion

If I've taken an undergrad Sipser-based theory course, and that's basically the extent of my knowledge, what tags should I follow to maximize the number of questions I can meaningfully answer on this site?

Comment: If that's your level, you'll probably be better at home on [cs.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some of these:

> [cc.complexity-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory), [ds.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms), [np-hardness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-hardness), [complexity-classes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity-classes), [fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fl.formal-languages), [automata-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata-theory)

Depending on your math background perhaps also [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), [co.combinatorics](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co.combinatorics).

A couple of caveats:

- As the most popular tag [cc.complexity-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory) gets about 1 question a day,
  compared to large sites like Math.StackExchange and Stack Overflow there is less of a need to follow only particular tags.
- The level of questions may be somewhat high as the site is [for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-traffic).

Comment: "The level of questions may be somewhat high as the site is for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields" Good point, I should ask this on CS.SE instead.